# I have a Angular material Menu inside a Material Dialog. On pressing ESC, Menu and Dialog both are closed. How to prevent dialog to not close on ESC?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-dialog

I have a mat menu inside mat dialog. After opening dialog and then menu inside it, i pressed esc to close the menu, but both menu and dialog are closed. How to close just the menu and not the dialog with ESC?

It can be reproduced here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzau6u

Answer (score 0):

You can add `disableClose: true` to the `dialogRef` configuration, to prevent the dialog closing from pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>. It's [explained in the API of the Dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api).

> `disableClose: boolean`
> Whether the user **can use escape or clicking on the backdrop** to close the modal.

```js
openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
    width: '250px',
    data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
    disableClose: true
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
    this.animal = result;
  });
}
```

See [this updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzau6u-ho3wcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts) for reference.

Comment: i don't want to disable ESC altogether, i just want to press ESC two times to close both Menu and Dialog, One for menu first then another ESC should close the modal.